# Send a variable from a class to another one

Tags: java

I have a Jframe class that has a login and password fields. When loggin on, i have to display informations of the person that logged in, so i have to retrieve his login from the first Jframe to make a treatment in the other one.
Here is that i made, but the login returns NULL in the second jframe:
First Jframe (login and password fields):

```
private void button_connectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String x= loginField.getText();
    String y= passwordField.getText();
    AuthentificationDAO authDAO= new AuthentificationDAO();
    boolean ok_login= authDAO.verify_login(x);
    int pass= Integer.parseInt(y);
    System.out.println("password retrieved"+pass);
    boolean ok_pass=authDAO.verify_password(pass);
    System.out.println("ok pass"+ok_pass);
    if (ok_login & ok_pass)
    {
        System.out.println("Login found!");
        Enseignant e= new Enseignant();
      edu.app.persistence.Enseignant ens= new edu.app.persistence.Enseignant(x);
      //ens.setLogin(x);
        System.out.println("login SET:"+ens.getLogin());
        e.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);


    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Login NOT found!");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Accourt NOT found. Please check your login or password.", "Check Login/Pass", 1);
    }
```

Second Jframe that will display informations of that login:

private void mauvaisFieldFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {

```
edu.app.persistence.Enseignant ens= new edu.app.persistence.Enseignant();
String login=ens.getLogin();
System.out.println("LOGIN EST:"+login);
StatsDAO stats= new StatsDAO();
int id=stats.get_id_from_login(login);
System.out.println("ID="+id);
```

}

Any idea please of how solving that problem?
Thank you very much.

Comment: could u post the code for `teach(x)` ?

Comment: First JFrame uses a local variable called `ens`. Second JFrame uses a variable called `ens` too. Where does it come from? What does `here it returns NULL` mean? (do you mean it *prints* null?). Also class names should hace a first capital leter (`Teach` instead of `teach`).

Comment: Is it the same instance of `edu.app.persist.teach`? (Also, not a great classname, and why not import that like the other classes?)

Comment: Teach(x) is just a constructor that will set login attribute. Here in my case i want to set login attribute with 'x' that is the text retrieved from TextField.

Comment: @DaveNewton: please take a look at the edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `ens.login` is `static`, this code won't work.

You can use the `MVC` pattern or you can just make your second frame class extends `JFrame`, in order to add a login field to it..

Sonething like :

```
    class1 {
        class2 frame2 = new class2();
        void login(){
            String x = loginField.getText();
            edu.app.persist.teach ens= new edu.app.persist.teach(x);
            class2.setLogin(x);
        }
   }

   class2 extends JFrame{
       String login;
       String getLogin(){..}
       void setLogin(String s){..}
       .
       .
   }
```

I've used a sort of pseudocode but it should be clear enough

Comment: If `ens.login` is `static` then any new user login will overwrite the `ens.login` value. Unless care is taken to login only one user at any given time, this doesn't work.

Comment: @Rakesh: so what do you purpose ?

Comment: I know, it was just to explain why it has null on the other JFrame. The code that I posted DOESN'T require it to be static.

Comment: @androniennn you can implement StepTNT's solution, it absolutely works but code your app to allow single login.

Comment: @StepTNT: `setLogin(String s)` method, is like this ? `public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }`

Comment: To add multiple logins, you can just move `class2 frame2 = new class2();
` inside the `login()` method of `class1` . So you'll create a new `class2 JFrame` everytime that a new user is logged

Comment: Yeah, just a basic setter for `String login` property, as `getLogin()` will just do `return login`

Comment: Glad that I helped you :) When you're done with your work, take some time to accept the answer if you found it useful :)